# Исчезает правый бордер при определенных размерах экрана. Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

Проблема проявляется в FF. Воспроизвел ее в коде: кликаете на кнопку, через секунду, после появления информациооного сообщения, появится скролл и у popup'a должен исчезнуть правый бордер. Если у Вас сразу не воспроизведется - попробуйте неспеша изменять ширину экрана и увидите, как мигает правый бордер. Зафиксируйте его отсутствие и заново запустите код.

Код нужно запускать развернутым на всю страницу в  ФФ

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template:`  <el-button :plain="true" @click="open1">message</el-button>`,
  methods: {
    open1() {
      document.body.style.height = "";
      setTimeout(()=>{
        document.body.style.height = "200vh";
      },1000)
      this.$message({
        showClose: true,
        dangerouslyUseHTMLString: true,
        message: '<p>Employee profile successfully created for this canddsfgsdgiddate</p>',
        duration: 600 * 1000,
        type: 'error'
      });
    },
  }
});
```

```css
.el-message {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  padding: 8px 20px !important;
  min-width: 301px !important;
  border-width: 1px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: а самому стилизовать это сообщение не вариант ? там если тот css удалить то всё хорошо отображается но только надо самому стилизовать кнопку и сообщение

Comment: @MaximLensky, в этих стилях и фишка же... они переопределяют  стили библиотеки. Или речь о чем-то другом?

Comment: Как я понимаю, баг возникает, если ширина блока вычисляется и не кратна пикселю. При появлении скрола размер блока уменьшается на ширину скрола (а он скорее всего занимает чётное количество пикселей) и опять 0.5 пикселя. Думаю, это баг браузера. Всё что вы можете сделать, это написать багрепорт и придумать пока какой-нибудь костыль.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин, сделал `min-width: 301.5px`, баг вроде исчез. Завтра, на работе, более детально протестирую. Спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем, методом научного тыка определил, что к такому эффекту приводит сочетание нечетного размера ширины документа с четной суммой левого и правого паддинга.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template:`  <el-button :plain="true" @click="open1">message</el-button>`,
  methods: {
    open1() {
      document.body.style.height = "";
      setTimeout(()=>{
        document.body.style.height = "200vh";
      },1000)
      this.$message({
        showClose: true,
        dangerouslyUseHTMLString: true,
        message: '<p>Employee profile successfully created for this canddsfgsdgiddate</p>',
        duration: 600 * 1000,
        type: 'error'
      });
    },
  }
});
```

```css
.el-message {
   background-color: #fff !important;
   min-width: 301px !important;
   border-width: 1px !important
   padding-top: 8px !important;
   padding-right: 21px !important;
   padding-bottom: 8px !important;
   padding-left: 20px !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```