# Элементы с дробной высотой рендерятся по разному

Tags: css, webkit, render

**Дано:** Hamburger из трех ровных линий, где линии состоят из (`::before + div + ::after`)
Правила заданы одинаковые, за исключением отступ margin-top для (`div + ::after`).

**Проблема:** Высота `div` - меньше на пиксель, чем `::before и ::after`. НО! Это только при определенных размера экрана. Так как высота строится от rem, который в свою очередь меняется от размера экрана.

**Решение:** Так как px иногда генерируются дробными, то в этом и есть вся проблема, также изменения margin иногда дает результат. Но интересно, почему линии генерируются так не по одному алгоритму. Возможно есть способ без медия, исправить эту не справедливость. В данный момент это не большая проблема, но не первый раз подобная проблема.

**P.S.:** Проблема встречается на webkit. Высота родителя не ограничена

```
.header-hamburger {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 1.5rem;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;

  & > *, &::after, &::before {
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: .1rem;
    background: $white;
    transition: all .3s;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }

  & > *, &::after {
    margin-top:  0.4rem;
  }

  &::before, &::after {
    content: '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Похожая проблема - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1010435/%d0%98%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Высота с дробным значением

Браузеры по разному округляют размеры с дробными числами – этой проблеме уже [не первый год](https://habr.com/ru/post/31392/). Хотя это даже не проблема, а нормальное поведение – нельзя "закрасить" половину пикселя или же его треть. В таком случае браузер для себя округляет значение и отрисовывает уже его – отличаются лишь алгоритмы.

Более того, даже выравнивание элемента с нечетной высотой через `display: flex` и `align-items: center` в разных браузерах будет иметь разный эффект – опять таки из-за округления в большую или меньшую сторону.

#### Как работает REM

**Есть несколько правил, которые помогут вам понять работу `rem`:**

- `rem` всегда относителен размеру шрифта корневого элемента – то есть
  к тегу `html`. Если размер шрифта `html` элемента равен `16px`, то `1rem` = `16px`, тогда как `.1rem` = `1.6px`.
- `rem` будет ВСЕГДА относителен корневому элементу, не полагаясь на
  вложенные элементы.

Таким образом, `rem` работает так: число, заданное в `rem`, умножается на `font-size` корневого элемента, а полученное значение отрисовывается браузером в `px`.

#### Как решить вашу проблему

Что касается вашей проблемы, её исправить можно двумя способами:

1. использовать фиксированные величины в `px`;
2. в `rem` указывать лишь те значения, которые при умножении на
   `font-size` корневого элемента будут выдавать целые числа.